# Angular Parent Scope Variable not changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

I have a parent controller where I set instantiate an object called links. I assign a property with a value that I want to change within another function. However when I set the variable in the instagramModel the links.imagesa  doesn't get updated.

I print the value out in the console and the parentscope doesn't get updated. I have thought I followed the rules of prototypical inheritance.

**Why is $scope.links.imagesa not updating?**

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function HomeController($scope, titleService, config, $sails, $timeout, $upload, leafletData, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.links = {};
    $scope.links.imagesa = "This should change";

    $scope.instagramModal = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'instagramModal.html',
            controller: 'InstagramModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $sails.get("/instagram/self").success(function (response) {

                        return response.data;

                    }).error(function (response) {
                        console.log('error');
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.links.imagesa = "wept";                

        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };

    $scope.ask = function () {
        console.log($scope.links.imagesa);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parent's scope to get updated, then you must use **$scope.$parent.links.imagesa** since the changes made in child scope are not reflected in the parent scope directly.

Comment: your answer gives - undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.$parent.links.imagesa = "wept"')

Comment: Ensure you have parent child hierarchy between the scopes or may be the links.imagesa is not present in the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

Angular UI's modals use $rootScope by default. See documentation at "http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal"

You can pass a scope parameter with a custom scope when you open the modal – e.g. scope: $scope if you want to pass the parent scope. The modal controller will create a sub-scope from that scope, so you will only be able to use it for your initial values.

Hence, if you want to update any value, keep the object/data in rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

I had the HomeCtrl instantiated in the UI Router and also on the template page using ng-controller. This messed up the scope.